# How to grab data from Firebase Realtime Database and return it in a function in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database

i am currently working on a project where users have accounts with information about them. And I want that every client can get and load the data with just the ID of the target. I wanted to solve this with a function, but i don't know how to return the data, I hope you can help me!

[Screenshot Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgzZm.png)

```
func getUserData(targetID: String)->String{
        
        let db = Database.database(url: "link")
        
        db
            .reference()
            .child("users")
            .child(targetID)
            .child("/username")
            .getData(completion:  { error, snapshot in
              guard error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return;
              }
                let userName = snapshot.value as? String ?? "null";
               });
        return userName //won't work, but how can I make it work? 
    }
```

Comment: Add screenshot of your firebase database structure

Comment: @Dilan I added the screenshot!